# What's the use of Trace Class and Debug Class in C#?

Tags: c#

I seem not to understand the concepts behind **Trace** and **Debug** Classes in **System.Diagnostic** package ! Can anybody briefly tell me what they all about ? I would appreciate if you include some examples!

Comment: One is used to help _trace_ a program, the other is used to help _debug_ it. It's pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN

[**Debug**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx)

> Make your code more robust without affecting the performance and code
>   size of your shipping product.

```
// Specify /d:DEBUG when compiling.

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Debug.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
       Debug.AutoFlush = true;
       Debug.Indent();
       Debug.WriteLine("Entering Main");
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World.");
       Debug.WriteLine("Exiting Main"); 
       Debug.Unindent();
    }
}
```

[**Tracing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx)

> Tracing helps you isolate problems and fix them without disturbing a running system

```
// Specify /d:TRACE when compiling.

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
       Trace.AutoFlush = true;
       Trace.Indent();
       Trace.WriteLine("Entering Main");
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World.");
       Trace.WriteLine("Exiting Main"); 
       Trace.Unindent();
    }
}
```

[How To Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6da106y8%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The comment  /d:TRACE is for what ?

Comment: These are called conditional attributes and are instructions to compiler wheather to compile those instruction or not. so /d:Trace means it compiler will compile all Trace instructions eg in given code almost all code lines are trance instrucitons so they will be complied and if you dont specifiy /d:Trace then they will not.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty obvious, Debug is for debugging, it won't affect the app in release build. Trace is used for something you need to know about when the apps running, it's supported by the framework. This link may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76dt1k3h(v=VS.100).aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788